# Waiting for onLoad event to finish before proceeding using ActionScript2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am using the following code to load a text file and get a value then assign it to another.

```
loadText = new LoadVars();
loadText.load("text.txt");

loadText.onLoad = function()
{
   _global.temp = this.myVariable;
};

...

var test = _global.temp;
```

After tracing I found that the `onLoad` event gets executed after `var test = _global.temp` statement. The above code block is available on the first frame. On the second frame, a code block acquires the value of test and calls a function. So, here is my question. Can I force the `onLoad` event to be executed before test assignment? Keep in mind that I am trying to modify an old SWF file without having the source for it. Thank you.

Comment: Loading data is an asynchronous operation, so you have to wait until the data is loaded to use it.

Comment: I tried using a while statement before 'test' assignment to make it go into an infinite loop until '_global.temp' has a value but that did not work.

Comment: After reading several articles, I realized I cannot accomplish what I want. I give up.

Comment: What do you want to do when the data is loaded ? How do you want to use  your `test` var ?